# "%" is not recognized as a normal text in SASS

Tags: css, sass

I have some trouble to use SASS.
I tried to make series of w-* classes.
For instance, I want "w-87" to be recognized "width: 87%;".
I have coded like below.

```
@for $i from 0 through 100 {
    .w {
        &-#{$i} {width: #{$i}%;}
    }
}
```

But the "%" symbol causes error.
Stackoverflow is my only hope.
Help me please.

Comment: Excuse me. I have made a mistake in my question. I had written "{font-size: #{$i}%;}", so I have edited it to "{width: #{$i}%;}"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `%` character is reserved as a **placeholder selector** ([see documentation](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/style-rules/placeholder-selectors)), so you will need to rely on [string interpolation](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/interpolation) to use `%` as a plain character:

```
@for $i from 0 through 100 {
    .w {
        &-#{$i} {font-size: #{$i}#{'%'};}
    }
}
```

However, a drawback of this approach is that interpolation will generate strings that cannot be used for further mathematical operations:

> Sass has powerful unit arithmetic that you can use instead. For example, instead of writing `#{$width}px`, write `$width * 1px`

The documentation suggests that you can also perform arithmetic operation in order to specify the unit:

```
@for $i from 0 through 100 {
    .w {
        &-#{$i} {font-size: $i * 1%;}
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. Your answer is very helpful and works well.

Answer (score 0):

You can multiply by `%`

```
  @for $i from 0 through 100 {
    .w {
      &-#{$i} {
        font-size: #{$i * 1%};
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thank your for your answer. Your answer works well. But I have checked Mr.Terry's answer instead of yours. His answer is written more details. Thank you again.